# c# Reflection - Find the Generic Type of a Collection

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, types

I'm reflecting a property 'Blah' its Type is ICollection

```
    public ICollection<string> Blah { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pi = GetType().GetProperty("Blah");
        MessageBox.Show(pi.PropertyType.ToString());
    }
```

This gives me (as you'd expect!) `ICollection<string>` ...

But really I want to get the collection type i.e. `ICollection` (rather than `ICollection<string>`) - does anyone know how i'd do this please?

Comment: But its type **is** `ICollection<string>`...

Comment: Agreed, `ICollection` and `ICollection<T>` are two completely different types.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're looking for the [`GetGenericTypeDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx) method:

```
MessageBox.Show(pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().ToString());
```

Comment: Note that this will return "ICollection`1[T]", which is CLR-speak for "ICollection<T>". I would have suggested the same, so +1.

Answer (score 34):

You'll want to look at [GetGenericTypeDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx) for example:

```
   List<String> strings=new List<string>();


        Console.WriteLine(strings.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition());
        foreach (var t in strings.GetType().GetGenericArguments())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t);

        }
```

This will output:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]
>   System.String

Comment: +1 for `GetGenericArguments`. That's actually what I was looking for when I landed here.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar but much more complicated problem... I wanted to determine if a type is assignable to collection type members or array type members dynamically.

So, here is better way how to get member type of collection or array dynamically with a validation if the type of an object to add is assignable to the collection or the array type members:

```
        List<IComparable> main = new List<IComparable>() { "str", "řetězec" };
        IComparable[] main0 = new IComparable[] { "str", "řetězec" };
        IEnumerable collection = (IEnumerable)main;
        //IEnumerable collection = (IEnumerable)main0;
        string str = (string) main[0];
        if (collection.GetType().IsArray)
        {
            if (collection.GetType().GetElementType().IsAssignableFrom(str.GetType()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Type \"" + str.GetType() + "\" is ok!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bad Collection Member Type");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (collection.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0].IsAssignableFrom(str.GetType()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Type \"" + str.GetType() + "\" is ok!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bad Collection Member Type");
            }
        }
```